# How to stop CSS3 animation in Android Browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, android-browser

I have a div which spins:

`<div class="medium animated"></div>`

```
.medium {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

.animated {
animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

I want it to stop when I click on it. I add `animation-play-state: paused` in onClick event listener and it works good everywhere except iOS and Android Browser

So, okay, I want just stop the animation on click in those browsers, not pause. So I remove `animated` class from the `DIV`. It works in iOS, but doesn't work in Android Browser. The `DIV` continues to spin.

How can I stop the animation in Android Browser?

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h603z2eh/) with an example

Comment: Add working code snippet on http://jsfiddle.net please.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov i've updated my post with the jsfiddle link

Comment: that's strange - it works in Android Browser.. then something else in my markup  or JS breaks this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out — http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/hpvqfut5/4/.

```js
$('.js-start-stop').on('click', function() {
    $('.js-circle').toggleClass('circle_animated');
});

$('.js-continue-pause').on('click', function() {
    $('.js-circle').toggleClass('circle_paused');
});
```

```css
.circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

    .circle__sector {
        float: left;
        width: 10%;
        height: 100%;
        background: yellow;
    }

    .circle_animated {
        -webkit-animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
        animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
    }

    .circle_paused {
        -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
        animation-play-state: paused;
    }

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }    
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle circle_animated js-circle">
    <div class="circle__sector"></div>
</div>
<button class="js-start-stop" type="button">Start/Stop</button>
<button class="js-continue-pause" type="button">Continue/Pause</button>
```

I tested on `Android Browser 4.1.2` and `iOS Safari 8.3` and could say so:

1. It seems like browser bug with `animation-play-state: paused`, cause CSS property is really applied in iOS Safari (I think on Android it's similar). I think you can do nothing with it.
   [image: Safari Web Inspector]
2. Button `Start/Stop` (animation) works well.